# How can I Scan file to search for value

Tags: java, file, variables, boolean

I need to scan an input file and search for a specific value. How do I do that?

Comment: What language?  (perhaps you can use grep)  (bah, I hate the 15 second limit after it fails to post because it was too short).

Comment: What does the input file data look like? What code have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what language?

in java: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html

Comment: is there anything more efficient tho. like i dont want it to search one byte at a time

Answer (score 2):

You could open a `Scanner` on a `File`, and with a `Scanner.findWithinHorizon()` you can search the very next occurrence of your research.

For example :

```
File file = new File("/Users/me/file.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
String foundString = scanner.findWithinHorizon("hello", 0); //You can replace Hello with a regex if you want.
```

---

**Resources :**

- [Javadoc - Scanner.findWithinHorizon()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findWithinHorizon%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)
- [Javadoc - File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

Answer (score 0):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

You can do nextInt() if you are looking for ints and so on.